# Discrete math counting question help

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

100 students from each of the 3 schools form a line. For each student (except the 1st and the last), the two neighboring students must be from 2 schools different than his/her school. The 1st and last student in the line must have his/her neighboring student from a school different than his/her school. How many ways are there to form such a line of 300 students?

Would it just be 100!*100!*100!*3 ?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can pick the school of the first student (three choices). Then you can pick the school for the second student (two choices). From then on the school of the stiudent is determined.

Within a school we have $100!$, so the answer is $6\cdot 100!^3$

Comment: Oh, good, I was just thinking that $3\cdot 100!^3$ seemed wrong.